# Create index for a few different queries on 4+ million row table

Tags: mysql, indexing

The table is currently a 4+ million (~50 GB) row table and growing rapidly.

We don't want to include any rows where the EndTime is invalid and thus less than StartTime, because there's at least 1,000 rows where it's zero.

My question is what kind index would be best for these three queries?
I'm guessing maybe a composite index with EndTime first and StartTime second?

The StartTime and EndTime fields both contain unix timestamps like: 1401951888

---

```
SELECT AVG(EndTime-StartTime) FROM sessions WHERE EndTime>StartTime;
SELECT MAX(EndTime-StartTime) FROM sessions WHERE EndTime>StartTime;
SELECT MIN(EndTime-StartTime) FROM sessions WHERE EndTime>StartTime;
```

---

```
+----------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Uuid                 | char(36)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| StartTime            | int(11)    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| EndTime              | int(11)    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The table is currently a 4+ million (~50 GB) row table and growing rapidly.

4M rows with just those 3 columns and it's 50GB? Wow... is there a problem somewhere?

> We don't want to include any rows where the EndTime is invalid and thus less than StartTime, because there's at least 1,000 rows where it's zero.

Since there are no other conditions, the query will have to process the entire table, minus 1000 rows. Therefore, any index will be useless.

Unless the table has lots more columns than you showed, in which case the only use for the index will be to be much smaller than the table on-disk, therefore much faster to scan.

Now, in recent versions of MySQL, you can now create [functional indexes](http://mysqlserverteam.com/virtual-columns-and-effective-functional-indexes-in-innodb/) on virtual columns! Therefore, you can create an index on:

```
endTime - startTime
```

If your max() and min() use the index, they will be instantaneous, since finding the min/max in a sorted set is a O(1) operation which only needs to look at the first or last entry. However, your avg() will, of course, have to examine all rows to compute the average.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that helped. 
Yes, there are other large blob columns, so it's ~50 GB.
I ended up doing a composite index like this:
    alter table sessions add index idx_times(EndTime,StartTime);
Now... queries run in secs vs. almost an hour each... this composite index with EndTime first seemed to do the trick for all queries.
Thanks, again for your help!

Comment: The "trick" is that the query can run entirely in the index.  That is, _all_ the columns mentioned in the query are in the index, so the index is "covering".  Still, it is an "index scan".  It is faster because there is less data to work with.  (UUIDs are terrible for performance, but that is another discussion, and only slightly relevant here.)